# Is transmission-daemon logging set-up properly?

Tags: debian, logs, transmission

I am having a question on GNU/Linux Debian 8.5 with `transmission-daemon` service.

I fail to see if there is a problem with how I set-up its log file. Because the log file does't grow (actually there's nothing).

First the manual:

> ```
> -e --logfile
> ```
>
> Where to store transmission's log messages.
>
> ```
> --log-error
> ```
>
> Show error messages
>
> ```
> --log-info
> ```
>
> Show error and info messages
>
> ```
> --log-debug
> ```
>
> Show error, info, and debug messages

Now, I will tell you all changes I've made today step by step:

I edited the default config file, `cat /etc/default/transmission-daemon`:

```
# defaults for transmission-daemon
# sourced by /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon

# Change to 0 to disable daemon
ENABLE_DAEMON=1

# This directory stores some runtime information, like torrent files 
# and links to the config file, which itself can be found in 
# /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json
CONFIG_DIR="/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info" 

# Default options for daemon, see transmission-daemon(1) for more options
OPTIONS="--config-dir $CONFIG_DIR --logfile /raid5/transmission/transmission.log --log-debug"

# (optional) extra options to start-stop-daemon
#START_STOP_OPTIONS="--iosched idle --nicelevel 10"
```

Is it a permission problem?

```
ls -l /raid5/transmission/transmission.log
-rwxrwx--- 1 debian-transmission debian-transmission 0 Aug  2 16:06 /raid5/transmission/transmission.log

ls -ld /raid5/transmission/
drwxrwx--- 3 debian-transmission debian-transmission 4096 Aug  2 16:06 /raid5/transmission/
```

I added myself (`vlastimil`) to `debian-transmission` group, though I believe this allows me to access the data and has nothing to do with logging:

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission vlastimil
```

I changed the ownership of `/raid5/transmission/`, which, among other things, allows me to download new torrents:

```
chown -R debian-transmission:debian-transmission /raid5/transmission/
```

I granted all permissions, that could be needed:

```
chmod 770 /raid5/transmission/
```

While having stopped the service, I edited `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` to have `umask` = 2:

```
cat /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json | grep umask

"umask": 2,
```

And of course I restarted service:

```
service transmission-daemon restart
```

Downloading and uploading works fine now, just the log is empty :/ Any clues?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.

I finally understood that the daemon is launched via `systemd`.

Edit this file:

```
/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service
```

And put these options there:

> ```
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-debug --logfile /var/log/transmission.log
> ```

Afterwards, run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart transmission-daemon
```

And it should be working fine now.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 this file is now located at `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service`.

Comment: /var/log is not accessible by debian-transmission for writing, so create a folder with suitable permissions for Transmission to be able to create the log file.

Comment: One should not edit files in `/lib` odr `/usr/lib`. Systemd has a command for customizing unit files: `systemctl edit --full transmission-daemon.service`.